# Rails application not visible to local network

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-yosemite

For the first time since upgrading to OSX Yosemite, I need to view an app running on my machine from another machine on the same network. Previously, this was as simple as finding my internal IP address and using that with port 3000, eg. `http://192.168.0.111:3000`.

However, I am now finding that with Yosemite this doesn't work. The application is definitely running and is available via `localhost:3000` but not via my internal IP.

I have run the network utility port scanner and it shows that localhost exposes port 3000 but my IP doesn't. Other machines on the network that have yet to upgrade (10.7.5 and 10.9.5) are not having this issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: According to the security and privacy pane of the system preferences, the Yosemite firewall is currently off - so that isn't causing the problem.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

By default, `rails server` will only accept connections from localhost. You can check this by looking at the console output:

```
Listening on localhost:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

To listen on all addresses, which will allow you to connect from other machines on the local network, you must explicitly bind to a more permissive address. Try this:

```
rails server --binding=0.0.0.0
```

You should now see:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Now you can connect to your Rails app from elsewhere on your local network, by browsing to e.g. `http://192.168.0.111:3000`.

Comment: Did that change come in with 4.2? I've got several other Rails 4.x projects and they still bind to 0.0.0.0... Thank you for that I wouldn't have even thought to look at rails itself.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure this was introduced in 4.2.0.

Comment: is there anyway where you can make this standard with 4.2.0. its annoying to type that in every time.

Comment: there is also a shortcut `rails s -b 0.0.0.0`

Comment: @SurgePedroza

If you want want to skip typing `rails server --binding=0.0.0.0`, seeing as how alot of projects now use [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) and have a Procfile for the server, sidekiq/resque/redis, Elasticsearch, Guard etc. You could easily just change the server line to something along the lines of:  

```ruby
     web: env bundle exec rails server --binding=0.0.0.0
```  

And now all you have to type is `foreman start` as usual and your server should be bound to the 0.0.0.0 ip_addr